# CSS Checkbox Styling Behaving Differently on Other Pages

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have a website I'm working on and I'm needing to change the styling of the check boxes when they are checked. Here is my CSS:

```
.settings-content input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.settings-content input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: url('../img/checkbox.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.settings-content input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url('../img/checkbox_checked.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.settings-content input[type="checkbox"] + label span{
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cosmetics" />
  <label for="cosmetics">
    <span></span>
  </label>
</li>
```

I got the checkboxes added on the homepage with the custom styling working perfectly on the homepage, but ran into a problem when trying to add checkboxes on other pages with the exact same markup and styling.

Here's my homepage with working check boxes:
http://tinyurl.com/pv62h8

Here's the settings page where the check boxes aren't working:
http://tinyurl.com/npfegb

You can see that on the settings page the background image has been changed properly, but when you click on the checkboxes nothing happens. They never go into a checked state. If I change the markup to make it checked by default it shows up as checked fine, but still nothing when clicking it.

I don't understand why it's not working since the styling is the same on both pages. I'm out of ideas on what the cause could be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some javascript or jquery thats working in conjunction with this?  It looks like the markup is different between the two pages and I suspect a selector is not finding the settings checkboxes.

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery. I have a custom JS script as well, but I tried removing that and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: The problem is in your custom JS/CSS.  The JS you have isn't selecting the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS isn't the same.

Home page uses:

```
.home-content input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span {
```

Settings page uses:

```
.settings-content input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
```

Is the "label" part supposed to be there?

**Edit**: Your JS uses .home-content to activate checkboxes. you need to add a reference to your .settings-content element to handle checks.

```
$('.home-search .dropdown-menu a, .sh-search .dropdown-menu a').on( 'click', function( event ) {

   var $target = $( event.currentTarget ),
       val = $target.attr( 'data-value' ),
       $inp = $target.find( 'input' ),
       idx;

   if ( ( idx = options.indexOf( val ) ) > -1 ) {
      options.splice( idx, 1 );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', false ) }, 0);
   } else {
      options.push( val );
      setTimeout( function() { $inp.prop( 'checked', true ) }, 0);
   }

   $( event.target ).blur();
   $(".home-search .dropdown-search-btn, .sh-search .dropdown-search-btn").text(options.join(", "));
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, the markup is slightly different but I believe it's the correct selector. The background image is being changed, it just doesn't change when you check it.